# Need help creating a simple macro in google sheets to create multiple charts from data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a simple macro script that creates a bar chart for every column of data I highlight.

[image: screenshot of google sheet]

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function macro1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B:B').activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asPieChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B6'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setPosition(5, 3, 137, 15)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B6'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'count')
  .setPosition(5, 3, 137, 15)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B6'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'count')
  .setPosition(5, 3, 137, 15)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('B1:B6'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'count')
  .setOption('series.0.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.0.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setPosition(5, 3, 137, 15)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};

function examplemacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn() - 3, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).activate();
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asPieChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'count')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'sum')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(0)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'sum')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'sum')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'sum')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  charts = sheet.getCharts();
  chart = charts[charts.length - 1];
  sheet.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asColumnChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 6, 1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('applyAggregateData', 0)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'false')
  .setOption('title', 'Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('pieSliceTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Count of Do you like fruit?')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('series.0.aggregateFunction', 'sum')
  .setOption('series.0.hasAnnotations', true)
  .setOption('series.0.dataLabel', 'value')
  .setPosition(10, 4, 100, 11)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

The example spreadsheet show 3 columns with questions and answers below it. There is also a macro 1 recorded.

What i'd like to do is create a macro whereby I was able to start with my curser highlighting the entire column and then run the macro to create a simple bar chart for the data in the column I highlighted.

The trouble is that even though I thought I was doing it right making sure I used relative values, when I try to run the macro in the next column it only runs for the column and data I originally highlighted in the macro..clearly I want it to work for whatever column I highlight.

Is there any macro wizz out there that can help? Much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your current code and also provide an image of your spreadsheet. Personally, I don't click on links to spreadsheets any longer.  Some people do.  Try to provide images to describe what you are trying to accomplish.  The easier you make it for us to understand what you want the better your chances are to get a quick and correct answer.

Comment: Just added Chris - hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Your highlighted range should store in this variable. 
`var currentRange = sheet.getActiveRange();`,

And then make sure to add this to your code
 `.addRange(currentRange)`

I can't read your code. So, try this.

```
function createBarChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var currentRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var currentA1Notation = currentRange.getA1Notation();
  var currentCol = currentRange.getColumn();

  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
    .addRange(currentRange)
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .build()
    .setTitle(sheet.getRange(1, currentCol).getDisplayValue());

  sheet.insertChart(chart)
}
```

More info:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-bar-chart-builder#addrangerange

Comment: Thanks Kingson - I'm not a programmer so dont really know what I'm doing...I've pasted the current screen shot and macro in this post now..hopefully that will help..thnaks for replying and tyrying to help